# Crear codigo que muestre en qué tramo de factura de la luz nos encontramos python

Tags: python, bucle-for, diccionarios

tengo un problema y es crear un código que dependiendo en qué hora te encuentras del dia te diga en qué tramo te encuentras, os pongo el ejemplo concreto:

He creado un diccionario con los tramos y las horas en que pertenecen:

```
`tramo_luz = {'punta':([10,11,12,13,14], [18,19,20,21,22]), 'valle': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'llano': 
([8,9], [15,16,17], [23,24])}`
```

Una vez lo tengo definido, necesito una lista con los dias de la semana laborales:

```
`dias = ['lunes', 'martes, 'miercoles', 'jueves', 'viernes']`
```

Y defino dos variables que seran las que me digan en el código el dia y la hora de las que quiero saber el tramo:

```
`dia = 'miercoles'`
`hora = 19`
```

Una vez tengo esto quiero hacer un código que dependiendo del dia y hora dichos me diga en qué tramo estoy y no se como continuarlo. He creado dos variables con las key y los valores del diccionario para poder recorrer el diccionario:

```
`tramo = tramo_luz.keys()`
`horas = tramo_luz.values()`
```

Y hacer un bucle for primero para que me diga en qué tramo me encuentro poniendo la variable 'hora', pero no veo como continuar:
`for tramo, horas in tramo_luz.items(): if horas == 'hora': print('Te encuentras en el tramo':, tramo)`

Comment: `tramo_luz` es igual para todos los días. ¿Donde se usa el día dentro del problema?

Comment: Si tus consultas son por hora, la llave del diccionario debería ser la hora, no la tarifa.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy importante la buena indexación de los datos de referencia para facilitar la abstracción del problema y luego transformar a código más simple. Con lo anterior, si el problema está abierto a cambios, yo modificaría el diccionario de datos a esta otra manera:

```
tramo_luz = {0:'llano',  1:'valle', ..., 23:'llano'}
```

Un simple diccionario unidimensional y con eso ya tienes el 50% del problema resuelto. Incluso, como está indexado ordenadamente, podrías prescidir de los indices y convertirlo a lista, pero pienso que en forma diccionario es más compresible.

Supongamos que es la hora 13 (1:xx PM)

```
>>> chour = 13 # Hora = 13
>>> tramo_luz(chour)
'punta'
```

Ahora bien, podemos hacer que el sistema calcule el momento en el que está.
[Documentacion1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timetuple), [Documentacion2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

```
import datetime

tramo_luz = {
    0:'llano',  1:'valle', 2:'valle', 3:'valle', 4:'valle',
    5:'valle',  6:'valle', 7:'valle', 8:'llano', 9:'llano',
    10:'punta',  11:'punta', 12:'punta', 13:'punta', 14:'punta',
    15:'llano',  16:'llano', 17:'llano', 18:'punta', 19:'punta',
    20:'punta',  21:'punta', 22:'punta', 23:'llano'}
dias = ['lunes', 'martes', 'miercoles', 'jueves', 'viernes', 'sabado', 'domingo']
cur_date = datetime.datetime.today()
cwday = cur_date.weekday() # 0 (lunes), ..., 6 (domingo)
cnday = cur_date.day # 1 - 31*
chour = cur_date.hour # 0 - 23
dsp_hour = cur_date.strftime('%H:%M')
print(f'{dias[cwday]} {cnday} {dsp_hour} - Se encuentra en el tramo: {tramo_luz[chour]}')
```

La salida en este momento, para mi región:

> lunes 25 11:53 - Se encuentra en el tramo: punta

Comment: muchas gracias me ha servido de mucho tu respuesta.